# equivalent of /opt/graphite/conf/ in yum-install of graphite+uwsgi+nginx

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, graphite

According to docs, default installation dir of graphite and graphite-web is **/opt/graphite/conf/** (when installed using pip or from source.)

My first query is: **What is the equivalent of /opt/graphite/conf/ when I do a yum-install of the relevant packages?**

I have yum-installed these on my Centos 7.8:  graphite-web-0.9.16-3.el7.noarch, uwsgi, and all other relevant packages. I am not using virtualenv. carbon-cache is up and collecting data.

Here is the https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-webapp.html#nginx-uwsgi doc that I am referring to.

Here are the directories and files created by the RPM's

```
ls -1 /etc/graphite-web/
dashboard.conf
local_settings.py
local_settings.pyc
local_settings.pyo

ls -1 /usr/share/graphite/
graphite-web.wsgi
webapp

 ls -1 /etc/uwsgi*
/etc/uwsgi.ini

/etc/uwsgi.d:
graphite-web.ini     <== created by me, see below

ls -1 /var/lib/carbon/
lists
rrd
whisper
```

And here are the contents of uwsgi.ini and graphite-web.ini

```
cat /etc/uwsgi.ini
[uwsgi]
uid = uwsgi
gid = uwsgi
emperor = /etc/uwsgi.d
chmod-socket = 660
emperor-tyrant = true
pidfile = /var/run/uwsgi/uwsgi.pid
cap = setgid,setuid


cat /etc/uwsgi.d/graphite-web.ini
[uwsgi]
processes = 2
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
gid = nginx
uid = nginx
chdir = /opt/graphite/conf   <== what should this be in my yum-installed case?
module = wsgi:application
```

Here is the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/graphite-web

```
server {
       listen 8080;
       server_name graphite;
       root /usr/share/graphite/webapp;
       error_log /var/log/nginx/graphite-web-error.log;
       access_log /var/log/nginx/graphite-web-access.log;

       location / {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
        }
}
```

I see the uwsgi server listening on 3031, but no service listening on 8080. When I try http://myservername/graphite the error log is */usr/share/ngix/html/graphite" failed (2: No such file or directory)*

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

To start off with, I don't know the answer to this directly since we install our graphite to a custom location.

However, perhaps using find command can help you locate the directory. Something like the following command may help:

```
$ sudo find /usr -type d -name conf | grep carbon
```

Example of my return result when I do this for our custom install directory:

```
$ sudo find /media/ephemeral0/ -type d -name conf | grep carbon
/media/ephemeral0/carbon/lib/django/conf
/media/ephemeral0/carbon/conf
```

If you weren't able to find this already, perhaps this will help.

Comment: Useful info given by Gies, thanks!. In meanwhile I had got going by opting for apache + mod_wsgi. That worked right away out of the box with yum install of all of graphite, apache, mod-wsgi .